# Error al actualizar en bucle con while en php me actualiza el mismo valor en todos los campos

Tags: php, mysql, while

tengo un ciclo hecho con while

php

$sql2= "SELECT precio from lineaspresupuestos WHERE idpresupuesto=[gidpresupuesto]";
sc_select(ds,$sql2);

```
            if ({ds} === false)
            {
            echo "Error con el Dataset =". {my_data_erro};
            }
            else
            {
            while (!{ds}->EOF)
            {               
                $precio={ds}->fields["precio"]*2;
                
             $sqlupdate="UPDATE lineaspresupuestos set precio='$precio' where idpresupuesto=[gidpresupuesto]";
                sc_exec_sql ($sqlupdate);
                
            {ds}->MoveNext();
        echo $precio ."<br>";
            }
    
    {ds}->Close(); 
            }


estos son los datos iniciales:
```

================================
idpresupuesto-----cant------precio 
================================
-------82--------- 1--------1.00  
-------82----------2--------2.00

cuando ejecuto el bucle me actualiza los datos mal, el valor '4' de la variable  $precio
me la actualiza en ambos registros que deberia actualizar

================================
idpresupuesto-----cant------precio 
================================
-------82--------- 1--------4.00  
-------82----------2--------4.00

que estoy haciendo mal? me pone el ultimo valor en toda la actualizacion

Comment: estimado, primero, por que usas {ds}, segundo, es mas simple usar un foreach para iterar entre cada resultado de una query.

Comment: hola el {ds} es el nombre del dataset, ok si me puedes dar luces de donde buscar info del foreach para este caso es que no se como plantearlo,

Comment: Claro, es normal... porque la consulta para actualizar se basa en el valor de idpresupuesto, dice `where idpresupuesto=[gidpresupuesto]`, y ambos registros tienen idpresupuesto=82, por lo tanto actualiza los dos. si dices `set precio=1000 where idpresupuesto=82` pues ambos registros tienen id 82 y seran actualizados con precio = 1000

Comment: Ook entiendo, y como hago para que me actualice un valor diferente en cada precio ? Dame una idea porfa !!